# Is module export create a new instance each time when import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
// src/utils/http.js
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
});

export default axiosInstance;''
```

when import the above module `import http from './http'` does it create a new axios instance each time? or it is singleton?

Answer (score 14):

["ES6 Modules are singletons - the instance is created when module is loaded."](https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern)